# Restrict usage of Heroku app by Authentication?

Tags: security, authentication, heroku

I developed my Heroku app that exposes APIs only (no UI) and it works fine.
But how can I restrict the APIs to certain authorized/authenticated users only?

I absolutely need an authentication layer to protect the app APIs and prevent unauthorized accesses. A sort of `login(user, psw)` call to use before an external system can start invoking my API.

But I don't find any reference in the docs, it only says that these are the main security best practices:

- [Heroku SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl)
- Force the use of HTTPS
- [Trusted IP Range](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-spaces#trusted-ip-ranges)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

That's something you'll need to implement at the application layer and not something that Heroku provides. At it's simplest you could implement basic auth in your app so that the user would pass them with their request, a more complex solution would involve user accounts and oauth etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement all the authentication logic directly in your app.
Alternatively, take a look [Auth0](https://auth0.com/), which basically provides you with authentication and identity management as a service. You can easily add Auth0 to your Heroku app as a free add-on via the [Heroku Elements marketplace](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/auth0).

They have lots of different use-cases and associated walk-throughs, and they offer a very generous free-tier.

From your requirements, it sounds like you might want to look at [Auth0 Machine to Machine applications](https://auth0.com/docs/applications/machine-to-machine), using the [OAuth2 Client Credentials Grant](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/grant/client-credentials). With that, your external system(s) would basically need to authenticate with Auth0 using a Client Id and Client Secret (that you could generate in Auth0 and supply to them). Then, they would access your API with a [JWT](https://jwt.io/) that you could easily validate in your app (Auth0 will provide you with generated code in many different languages for you to do that very easily). Your API will then reject requests without a valid JWT (by sending a "401 Unauthorized" response).

This may all sound a little intimidating at first, but it's really worth going through the relevant Auth0 "quickstart". They really go out of their way to try to make it as easy as possible!